# How to call directly a returned anonymous function in php

Tags: php, dependencies, callable

I'm trying to call directly a returned function and passing an argument, but it seems I have to do it in two times.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $signup_db = $configOptions['db']['signup_db'];

    // setup the infos of the db connection in an object
    $dbInfos = new DBInfos();
    $dbInfos->setEngine( $signup_db['engine'] );
    $dbInfos->setHost( $signup_db['host'] );
    $dbInfos->setDbName( $signup_db['dbname'] );
    $dbInfos->setUser( $signup_db['user'] );
    $dbInfos->setPassword( $signup_db['password'] );

    // create the Inversion of Control object for dependency injection.
    $ioc = new IOC();

    // create a new database connection with a PDO object.
    $ioc->dbh = function($dbInfos) {
        try {
            PDOconfig::setDbInfos($dbInfos);
            $dbh = new PDOconfig();
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        }
        return $dbh;
    };

    $dbh = $ioc->dbh;
    $dbh = $dbh($dbInfos);

    // default page if empty.
    if (empty($_GET)) {
        $_GET["page"] = "home";
    }
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        $variables = array("page" => $page, 
                           "ioc" => $ioc);

        if ($page == "home") {
            renderLayoutWithContentFile("home.php", $variables);            
        } else if ($page == "contact") {
            renderLayoutWithContentFile("contact.php", $variables);
        } else if ($page == "about") {
            renderLayoutWithContentFile("about.php", $variables);
        }
    }  
?>
```

This is IOC class:

```
<?php

// Inversion of control with magic methods
// its pupose is to serve as a container for dependency injection
class IOC {
    private $registry = array();

    public function __set($name, $resolver) {
        $this->registry[$name] = $resolver;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->registry[$name];
    }
}

?>
```

I would like to transform this:

```
$dbh = $ioc->dbh;
$dbh = $dbh($dbInfos);
```

by this unique line of code:

```
$dbh = $ioc->dbh($dbInfos);
```

But I have an error if I do that:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method IOC::dbh() in domain.com/public/index.php on line 34
```

That doesn't make sense to me.
Does someone know how to deal with this ?

Comment: (PHP regularly doesn't makes sense. It's simply badly implemented. It's the same with creating and object and calling a method on it in the same line) Can you please narrow your example so that everybody can reproduce it.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I think it's possible since 5.5.

Comment: Have a look at call_user_func_array function. It might help.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois: I use PHP 5.3.26. I will try with 5.5

Comment: @Petr Jirouš: looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What these lines are doing:

```
$dbh = $ioc->dbh;
$dbh = $dbh($dbInfos);
```

is `$dbh` is assigned to a function and then you are passing `$dbInfos` to it. While what you are trying to do is calling a function `dbh` with parameters `$dbInfos` of the class `IOC` which actually doesn't exist. See the difference here..which is why you are getting the undefined call error.

If you really want to do that, try creating a function in `IOC` class and then proceed with what you are doing i.e `$dbh = $ioc->dbh($dbInfos);`..

I hope this helps..

Comment: It definitely helps! Indeed, what actually doesn't make sense is what I am trying to do. The magic function __get() works with a class instance, not with a function.